# Delete a DOM element and its associated jquery plugin and data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

1. First, I'm using a jquery plugin on an element, lets say `$('#myElement').usePlugin();`.
2. Second, I want to destroy the original element and any plugin variables etc that may still exist in JS.
3. Third, create a new `#myElement` and redo `$('#myElement').usePlugin();`.

I'm having trouble with step #2. When I do `$('#myElement').remove()`, there is residual strange behavior when I recreate the element and instantiate the plugin.

FYI: this is the plugin I'm having trouble with: http://mindmup.github.io/editable-table/. If I create a table, make it editable, everything works fine.

But then if I delete the table, recreate the table, make it editable, I get strange behavior where fields are editable, but when I hit "enter", the value does not save and I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trigger' of undefined`.

Comment: Unfortunately that plugin doesn't have a built-in destroy method. Therefore, you'll have to undo any delegated or global events added by the plugin, such as the window resize event. a quick fix would be to remove all event handlers listening to the window resize event, however that obviously can impact code other than this plugin too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would modify this line in the plugin:

https://github.com/mindmup/editable-table/blob/master/mindmup-editabletable.js#L115

to:

```
    $(window).on('resize.mindmup', function () {
```

Now, when you want to remove that event, remove it by namespace.

```
$(window).off("resize.mindmup");
```

Continue removing and re-creating the table, then use the above line to remove the window resize event before re-initializing the plugin.

Comment: so that only deals with the one of many events in this plugin correct? I'd have to go through and do this process for all the other events?

Comment: It's the only one i saw, but yes if there are more they will need the same treatment. You only need to worry about events that are added to elements outside of the table, anything on or inside the table will be cleaned up by `.remove()`

Comment: So I just deleted lines 115 through 121, since for now I don't need the resizing and just wanted to test if that was the source of this bug. Unfortunately it's still broken.

Comment: sounds like a bug in the plugin... the error is happening here: https://github.com/mindmup/editable-table/blob/master/mindmup-editabletable.js#L39 which means `text` is undefined, which means `editor` isn't an input element.... very odd.